# How can hide sensitive info in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to do this in SQL server:

If I have a name like 'Johnny English',

how can I show in a query this 'J***** E******'?

Thanks!

Comment: what version of SQL Server?

Comment: What if there's 3 words, or just 1?

Comment: Do you mean when you return the data or when it is stored?

Comment: I have SQL Server > 2008, @JamesZ Actually doesn't care i need only for the first name

Comment: @SeanLange when return data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume you have two columns of data here and you want only the first character but the rest of the characters as asterisks. You can do this using REPLICATE.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replicate-transact-sql

```
declare @FirstName varchar(20) = 'Johnny'
    , @LastName varchar(20) = 'English'

select left(@FirstName, 1) + replicate('*', len(@FirstName) - 1) + ' ' + left(@LastName, 1) + replicate('*', len(@LastName) - 1)
```

Comment: Thanks, that is what i need! Ty

Answer (score 0):

This code will add stars to the first word. It assumes the subsequent words are separated by at least one space

```
declare @test varchar(20)='Johnny English'
declare @StarNum int

set @StarNum=charindex(' ',@test)-2

select stuff(@test,2,@StarNum,replicate('*',@StarNum))
```